# How do you align text over 100% width div?

Tags: css, html

So I have a header which is set to 100% width on my page and I want to put text on the banner and stay in place but when I zoom in and out the position of the text changes. How do I make it so that the text stays place to the place I set it and zooming in and out does not affect it?

**Fiddle** : [jsfiddle.net/5ASJv/](http://jsfiddle.net/5ASJv/)

html

```
<div id="wrap">
<div class="right">
   Hey <br />
    What is up <br />
</div></div>
```

css

```
* {
margin: 0 auto;
}

#wrap {
height: 150px;
width: 100%;
background: url(http://froggyadventures.com/wp-content/uploads/galleries/post-93/full/placeholder%20-%20Copy%20(2).gif) no-repeat center;
text-align: center;
background-color: #FFF;
}
.right{
width: 400px;
height: 110px;
position: relative;
z-index: 999;
top: 100px;
left: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Why you are using `.right`? http://jsfiddle.net/5ASJv/1/

Comment: I agree with. Mr alien. The text cannot be aligned when in the div right

Answer (score 0):

In your case and approach if you want to give absolute position to the .right and want the text to be appeared wherever you set it then use the following in your `.right` class.

```
left:50%;
margin-left:-100px;
```

Comment: set the position according to your own requirements in margin-left.